# Apache Digester Pattern : need something like XSLT's '.' or 'current()'

Tags: xml, design-patterns, apache-commons-digester

I'm trying to use Apache Digester (V3) to process an XML file which contains 'thread-dumps' : so file contains many thread-dumps, one thread-dump contains many threads, and one thread contains a stacktrace, which consists of many lines

Like this: (Simplified)

```
<threaddumps>
<threaddump name="xxx">
<thread name="thread-1">
<stacktrace>
<line>
java.lang.wait
</line>
<line>
...
</line>
</stacktrace>
</thread>
<thread name="thread-2">
...
</threaddump>
<threaddump name="yyy">
...
</threaddumps>
```

I am using a XML-based rule to process this input file; fragment below:

```
<pattern value="thread">
                <object-create-rule classname="mypackagemodel.Thread"/>
                <set-next-rule methodname="addThread" paramtype="mypackagemodel.Thread"/>
                <set-properties-rule>
                    <alias attr-name="name" prop-name="name" />
                </set-properties-rule>
                <pattern value="stacktrace/line">
                        <object-create-rule classname="mypackagemodel.StackLine"/>
                        <set-next-rule methodname="addStackLine" paramtype="mypackagemodel.StackLine"/>
                        <!-- need something here -->
                </pattern>  
</pattern>
```

How do I pull that text out from the in between 'line' tags though ? I'm already matching on 'stacktrace/line', there is no sub-element to use - so what pattern can I use ?

Another way of putting it - The 'StackLine' object is being created and associated correctly - its just that I don't know what to call my 'setName()' setter with ?

(In XSLT one would generally use '.' or 'current()' in a similar scenario for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it : apparently an empty pattern string will match the current node's text:

This worked for me:

```
<bean-property-setter-rule pattern="" propertyname="line"/>
```